# How to validate date only in this format mm/dd/yy?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can you please tell me how to validate date only when in this format mm/dd/yy ? I actually found a solution but it also returns true when mm-dd-yy.

I need only it return true when the format is mm/dd/yy.

Here is my fiddle
:
http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/Hk2tc/

```
alert(isDate("1/12/1234"));

function isDate(txtDate)

{

  var currVal = txtDate;

  if(currVal == '')

    return false;



  //Declare Regex 

  var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;

  var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern); // is format OK?



  if (dtArray == null)

     return false;



  //Checks for mm/dd/yyyy format.

  dtMonth = dtArray[1];

  dtDay= dtArray[3];

  dtYear = dtArray[5];



  if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth > 12)

      return false;

  else if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay> 31)

      return false;

  else if ((dtMonth==4 || dtMonth==6 || dtMonth==9 || dtMonth==11) && dtDay ==31)

      return false;

  else if (dtMonth == 2)

  {

     var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));

     if (dtDay> 29 || (dtDay ==29 && !isleap))

          return false;

  }

  return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `-` in `var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;`.
You are not filtering `-`.
Check this Updated  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk2tc/2/)

Answer (score 1):

your problem is your regex... it also accept the `/` char.
Change to

```
 var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(-)(\d{1,2})(-)(\d{4})$/;
```

however, this regex also accepts dates like 40-40-9999... 
and of course, you don't have the day 40 in the 40th month ;)

check this link for help
http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the regex...

`(\/|-)` means "accept either `/` or `-` character".

Try changing this line:

```
var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/;
```

To this:

```
var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/)(\d{1,2})(\/)(\d{4})$/;
```

The difference is that both occurrences of `(\/|-)` were replaced with `(\/)`, which only matches `/`.